# How to set max time and min time in c# datetime picker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I am using a datetime picker in c# windows forms application.

How to set the the min time and max time ? I have a string "07:52:22" and I want to set this as the max or min time. How can I do this ?

```
DatetimePicker.MinDate.TimeOfDay = "07:52:22";
```

This is wrong but this is what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTimePicker datePicker = new DateTimePicker;
dateTimePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Parse("7:52:22");
```

Comment: This is for `MinDate` not `Min time`

Comment: @awudoin this perfect. I dont know why you got a downvote. This is exactly what I want. Thanks

Comment: @AkashDeshpande try this: `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);` <--- **If you inadvertently do this, your MinDate won't work as you expect** That's how `MinDate` works. **IT'S FOR DATETIME** not only `Time`.

Comment: @King Kong: While `DateTime` is **often** used to store both date and time, it is perfectly capable of storing only time values. Regardless, the OP wants to use a `DateTimePicker` which stores its value in a `DateTime` so he needs to work with this struct. In addition, the `DateTimePicker` has support for picking/storing time (although limited support). There is no reason to make it more complicated than it needs to be. Both the control and the struct supports what he is looking for....

Comment: @awudoin I didn't say it didn't support `Time`, it's just `MinDate` won't work **perfectly**, the `dateTimePicker1.Value` can be changed **freely**, somehow if that happens, the `MinDate` might not work as pointed out by the example in my previous comment. In fact, **we need** more code to make it work as expected or simply use the code of Mr Hans. **We do encounter the case in which we need to use Date part but still want some restriction to Time part**, in that case `MinDate` **can't help**.

Comment: The question wasn't whether `MinDate` would work but simply how to set it to the min value. `MinDate` would never work for directly setting programatically. It only works for the picker. If you saying the user can set the date...not true. Set the `DateTimePicker` to only time then the user cannot set a date. Open the calendar and only the dates within the bounds are selectable.... Not sure what you're getting at??

Comment: @awudoin **I didn't say user changes the Date part**, I want to mean **It's you, programmer?,** may change it in the code **inadvertently**

Comment: As I said...`MinDate` will never work for setting programatically (via code) even if you were worried about setting date. This point is moot in this context. `MinDate` was never supposed to protect against the programmer.... Again, not sure what your point is.

Comment: @awudoin Have you even tried the code in my example pointing out `MinDate` won't work in that case? `MinDate` is a property with `getter` and `setter`, why would you think it will never work for setting programmatically? I don't get any words uttered out from your mouth

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37789/discussion-between-awudoin-and-king-king)

Answer (score 5):

Right, not supported.  You'll have to add the validation yourself with the ValueChanged event.  You could just limit it like this:

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var max = new TimeSpan(7, 52, 22);
        if (dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay >= max) {
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + max;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is supported. `DateTime` stores time values as well. Review answers below.

Comment: Hans, Won't this result in `StackOverflowException`.. ? Appears to be a small bug :)

Comment: @awudoin it's just for `MinDate` and `MaxDate` (of type `DateTime`), what will the `Date` be if you just set `Time part` for it? When validating, it would check for `Date` part first

Comment: @King Kong: OP didn't say he was worried about the date...just the time. The `DateTimePicker` is often used to just pick/store time so I assumed that's what the OP wanted since that is all the stated.

Comment: No, no stack overflow.  The second pass doesn't enter the if() statement.  This answer works for any format.

Comment: Yes, It works. `ValueChanged` fires only when there is change. Indeed setting `MaxDate` with time also works

Comment: @SriramSakthivel really? How `MaxDate` works? This code works in any case while `MaxDate` works only when the `Date` part is fixed. That means we **do have to prevent the Date part from being changed**.

Comment: @KingKing Ah, OP actually mean to allow any date but restrict only time? I thought to prevent Date and Time.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I don't even know what the OP mean, but if he meant to use `Time` only, the `Date` part is still able to be changed **inadvertently** by his code (of course if we don't add code to prevent this).