# SharePoint DateTimeControl Time Range

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint **DateTimeControl** to capture a DateTime value. Customer is requesting to limit the time part of the control to only accept time from 7:00 AM to 6:00 PM for example.

I get back to the reference of the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms455639(v=office.14)) but all what I can get is the **MaxDate** and **MinDate** properties.

I tried to play with those properties as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934795/how-to-set-max-time-and-min-time-in-c-sharp-datetime-picker)  with no luck.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use JavaScript code below to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select[name$='Hours'] option").each(function(){
        if($(this).val().match(/^(([1-6]|12) AM)|(([7-9]|1[0-1]) PM)/g)) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @LZ_MSFT . Your answer did exactly what is required :)